# Calculations involving numpy arrays of different shapes without for loops?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code.

```
import numpy as np

perp = np.zeros(shape=(100, 3))
perp[:,0] = np.linspace(1,100,100)
perp[:,1] = np.linspace(1,200,100)
perp[:,2] = np.linspace(-25,25,100)
relDist = np.linspace(0,49,50)

posCoord = np.zeros(shape=(100, 50, 3))
posMask  = np.where(perp[:,2] >= 0)
negMask  = np.where(perp[:,2] < 0)

posCoord[posMask,:,1] = perp[posMask,1] + relDist[:] / np.sqrt(1 + perp[posMask,2]**2)
posCoord[negMask,:,1] = perp[negMask,1] - relDist[:] / np.sqrt(1 + perp[negMask,2]**2)
posCoord[:,:,0]       = (perp[:,2] * posCoord[:,:,1]) + perp[:,3]
```

As you can see, for every element in perp, I need to calculate an array of values of length relDist, and save it to the location posCoord[perp,relCoord,:]. At the moment I get an index error as I cant broadcast relDist and perp together.

I can do it with a loop, which for 100 elements doesnt take long, but in reality I have around 10000 elements in perp. Can someone help me vectorize this? I am really struggling. Obviously perp and relDist are different in my actual code, but this is a MWE.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean this `(perp[:,1,None] * posCoord[:,:,1]) + perp[:,2,None]`

Comment: The code works except for the last line, as pointed by Brenlla, and the `np.where` lines, which should have `[0]` at the end.

Comment: Also, indexing of `perp` in last line is wrong, `perp` has 3 columns and thus valid indexes are `0,1,2` but not `3`

Comment: Ah, I understand. So first up, the index in the last line is wrong, yes. That was the one bit of the MWE I didnt check, and is copied from my real code where 3 is a valid index. 

It appears I need lots of ,None in my array indices, otherwise the shape gets confused. Thanks.

Comment: When broadcasting arrays, the trailing `None` (`newaxis`) have to be explicit.  `numpy` automatically adds the leading ones.  That way there's no ambiguity, and neither you or `numpy` gets confused.